# var is undefined in a Gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, array, json, block-editor

I'm fiddling with Gutenberg right now and I'm stuck trying to build a dynamic block. This is the code I'm using (some code is omitted for clarity):

```
registerBlockType( 'my/block', {
    title: __( 'My Block' ),
    icon: 'email',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        menu: {
            type: 'string',
            default: '',
        },
    },

    edit: withAPIData( ( props ) => {
        return {
            menu_selected: `/menus/v1/menus/${ props.attributes.menu }` // custom endpoint
        };
    } ) ( ( props ) => {
        const attributes = props.attributes;
        const menu_selected = props.menu_selected.data;

        const setMenu = value => {
            props.setAttributes( { menu: value } );
        };

        console.log( JSON.stringify( menu_selected ) );

        const ar = menu_selected.map( ( item ) => {
                        return (
                            <li className="menu_item">
                            { item.post_title }
                            </li>
                        );
                    } );
    }
} );
```

`console.log( JSON.stringify( menu_selected ) )` returns the following string:

```
[{"ID":3729,"post_title":"Item 1","post_type":"nav_menu_item"},
{"ID":3730,"post_title":"Item 2","post_type":"nav_menu_item"}]
```

But when I call `map()` on the `menu_selected` var I get a "menu_selected is undefined" error and I don't understand why.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: is that the full error? Bonus tip, you can remove the `JSON.stringify` and call console.log directly on the object/array and it'll appear in the console letting you expand and collapse, and even copy it into the clipboard. It's possible this is Babel/Webpack related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to pass in `menu_selected`

```
edit: withAPIData( ( props ) => {
    return {
        menu_selected: `/menus/v1/menus/${ props.attributes.menu }` // custom endpoint
    };
} ) ( ( { menu_selected } ) => {
```

I was able to do a very similar thing like so:

```
edit: withAPIData( () => {
    return {
        posts: '/wp/v2/images?per_page=4&_embed'
    };
  } )( ( { posts, className } ) => {
      if ( ! posts.data ) {
          return "loading !";
      }
      if ( posts.data.length === 0 ) {
          return "No posts";
      }
```

Comment: Thanks! Looking at your second snippet of code I realized that I forgot to check if the `menu_selected` var was already populated with data coming from the REST API endpoint.